# Android app does not show images from external sources (http://...) after web site was converted using appsgeyser

Tags: android, html, css, web-applications

after I coverted my web-site (django-html-css) into a web-based application for android using appsgeyser, it does not show images. Images are coded in the following form:
http://www...' />

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

https:// instead of http was the problem.